# Input entry is not catched in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to build an application in which , there is one HTML page from which I get single input entry by using `Submit button`, and stores in the container(data structure) and `dynamically show that list` i.e., list of strings, on the same page

> means whenever I click submit button, that entry will automatically
>   append on the existing list on the same page.

But in this task, firstly I try to catch that input in javascript file, and I am failing in the same. Can you tell me for this, which command will I use ?

Till now my work is :-

**HTML FILE :-**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "operation_q_2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Enter String : <input type= "text" name = "name" id = "name_id"/>
        <button type="button"   onClick = "addString(this.input)">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT FILE:-**

```
function addString(x) {
    var val = x.name.value;
    //var s = document.getElementById("name_id").getElementValue;//x.name.value;
    alert(val);
}
```

**EDITED**

**My New JAVASCRIPT FILE IS :-**

```
var input = [];

function addString(x) {
    var s = document.getElementById("name_id").value;//x.name.value;
    input.push(input);
    var size = input.length;
    //alert(size);
    printArray(size);
}

function printArray(size){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < size; ++i) {
        div.innerHTML += input[i] + "<br />";
    }
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    //alert(size);
}
```

Here it stores the strings in the string, but unable to show on the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MjyRt/

Javascript was almost right

```
function addString(x) {
    var s = document.getElementById("name_id").value;//x.name.value;
    alert(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I spent a lot time only to do this. :(

Comment: Can you tell me any good site from where I can search any thing regarding javascript coding?

Comment: If you want to learn Native Javascript, don't use jQuery. If you want to have easy Javascript, where the library will take care of 90% use jQuery.

Comment: @Neils : I stuck again, new problem occur. Please help. Read my Edited Code

Comment: The `++i` should be `i++`. Because `++1` increases the value before it is read. and `i++` afterwards. You're index was too high and started at 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery (simpler)

```
 function addString() {

   var s = $('#name_id').val();//value of input;

    $('#list').append(s+"<br/>");//list with entries  
}


<div id='list'>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :)
But I have to do these assignments in javascript + HTML + CSS. (Its my initial stage). When I will get good knowledge in these , then I will jump into jQuery.